# Analytical solution of heat equation with non-homogenous boundary conditions

Tags: boundary-value-problem, initial-value-problems, parabolic-pde

I am trying to get analytical solution of heat equation with non-homogenous boundary conditions, which i can code in MATLAB and compare with my numerical results.

In short, i am unable to reach the correct analytical solution. Can someone help me with this. Here is the equation with BCs:

$\frac{\partial{u(x,t)}}{\partial{t}} = \alpha\frac{\partial^2{u(x,t)}}{\partial{x^2}}$ $\qquad$ (where $0<x<L$ and $t>0$)

where $\alpha$ is the thermal diffusivity.

IC: $u(x,0)= f(x)$

BC1: $u(0,t)= a(t)$

BC2: $u(L,t)= b(t)$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dis you try  $u(x,t) = X(x)T(t)$?

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\left.\partiald{\mrm{u}\pars{x,t}}{t} =
> \alpha\,\partiald[2]{\mrm{u}\pars{x,t}}{x}
> \right\vert_{\ {\Large x\ \in\ \pars{0,L}} \atop\
> {\Large t\ \in\ \pars{0,\infty}}}.\qquad}$
>   $\ds{\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
> \ds{\mrm{u}\pars{x,0}} & \ds{\equiv} & \ds{\mrm{f}\pars{x}}
> \\
> \ds{\mrm{u}\pars{0,t}} & \ds{\equiv} & \ds{\mrm{a}\pars{t}}
> \\
> \ds{\mrm{u}\pars{L,t}} & \ds{\equiv} & \ds{\mrm{b}\pars{t}}
> \end{array}\right.}$

\begin{equation}
\mbox{Lets}\ \mrm{u}\pars{x,t} \equiv
\mrm{a}\pars{t} + \bracks{\mrm{b}\pars{t} - \mrm{a}\pars{t}}{x \over L} + \mrm{U}\pars{x,t}
\end{equation}
such that
\begin{align}
&\partiald{\mrm{U}\pars{x,t}}{t} - \alpha\,\partiald[2]{\mrm{U}\pars{x,t}}{x} =
-\dot{\mrm{a}}\pars{t} - \bracks{\dot{\mrm{b}}\pars{t} - \dot{\mrm{a}}\pars{t}}{x \over L}
\\[5mm] &\
\mrm{U}\pars{x,0} \equiv
\mrm{f}\pars{x} - \mrm{a}\pars{0} - \bracks{\mrm{b}\pars{0} - \mrm{a}\pars{0}}{x \over L} \equiv \,\mrm{F}\pars{x}
\label{1}\tag{1}
\\[5mm] &\
\ds{\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{\mrm{U}\pars{0,t}} & \ds{\equiv} & \ds{0}
\\
\ds{\mrm{U}\pars{L,t}} & \ds{\equiv} & \ds{0}
\end{array}\right.}
\end{align}

---

Then,
$\ds{\mrm{U}\pars{x,t} =
\sum_{n =1}^{\infty}\mrm{A}_{n}\pars{t}
\sin\pars{{n\pi \over L}x}}$ which leads to
\begin{align}
\sum_{m =1}^{\infty}\bracks{\dot{\mrm{A}}_{m}\pars{t} + {m^{2} \over L^{2}}\mrm{A}_{m}\pars{t}}\sin\pars{{m\pi \over L}x} =
-\dot{\mrm{a}}\pars{t} - \bracks{\dot{\mrm{b}}\pars{t} - \dot{\mrm{a}}\pars{t}}{x \over L}
\end{align}

> Multiply both sides by $\ds{\sin\pars{n\pi x/L}}$ and integrate over $\ds{\pars{0,L}}$:

\begin{align}
&\dot{\mrm{A}}_{n}\pars{t} + {n^{2} \over L^{2}}\mrm{A}_{n}\pars{t} =
2\,{\pars{-1}^{n}\,\dot{\mrm{b}}\pars{t} - \dot{\mrm{a}}\pars{t} \over n\pi}
\\[5mm] &\
\totald{\bracks{\mrm{A}_{n}\pars{t}\exp\pars{n^{2}t/L^{2}}}}{t} =
2\,{\pars{-1}^{n}\,\dot{\mrm{b}}\pars{t} - \dot{\mrm{a}}\pars{t} \over n\pi}\,\exp\pars{{n^{2} \over L^{2}}\,t}
\\[1cm] &\
\mrm{A}_{n}\pars{t}\exp\pars{{n^{2} \over L^{2}}\,t} -
\mrm{A}_{n}\pars{0}
\\[2mm] = &\
{2 \over n\pi}
\int_{0}^{t}\bracks{\pars{-1}^{n}\dot{\mrm{b}}\pars{\tau} - \dot{\mrm{a}}\pars{\tau}
\exp\pars{{n^{2} \over L^{2}}\,\tau}}\dd\tau
\label{2}\tag{2}
\end{align}

> \eqref{2} determines $\ds{\mrm{A}_{n}\pars{t}}$ in terms of
>   $\ds{\mrm{A}_{n}\pars{0}}$ which can be later find with \eqref{1}.

I hope you work out some details !!!.

Comment: Hello Felix. Thanks for the answer. I am not able to understand the difference between t and \tau. BR.

Comment: @omerbilal You want the evaluation for a given $\displaystyle\color{red}{t}$. So, you have to choose any other character as an integration variable. In this case, I used $\displaystyle\color{red}{\tau}$.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the clarification. Here is the answer in terms of Fourier series.

$u(x,t) = a(t) + [b(t)-a(t)]\frac{x}{L} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} [\tilde{\phi_{n}} {e^{-\alpha(\frac{n\pi}{L})^2t} + \int_{0}^{t}} e^{{\alpha}(\frac{n\pi}{L})^2(\tau -t)}\tilde{f}{_{n}(\tau)d\tau}]sin\frac{n\pi x}{L}$

where; $\tilde{\phi}_{n} = \frac{2}{L}\int_{0}^{L}\tilde{\phi(x)}sin\frac{n\pi x}{L}dx$

and; $\tilde{f_{n}(t)} = \frac{2}{L}\int_{0}^{L}\tilde{f}(x,t)sin\frac{n\pi x}{L}dx$

also; $\tilde{\phi(x)} = f(x)-(1-\frac{x}{L})a(0) - \frac{x}{L}b(0)$

and; $\tilde{f}(x,t) = -(1-\frac{x}{L})\dot{a}(t) - \frac{x}{L}\dot{b}(t)$

BR.